# How do I remove the feature where newly written text in editor is highlighted?

Tags: overleaf, syntax-highlighting

Whenever I write something new in the overleaf editor on my laptop it highlights it (see attatched image below) and I have to manually click somewhere else in the editor in order to remove it. I haven't been home in a couple of months but I don't remember having this feature on my desktop computer. I find this very annoying as it's harder to read what I'm currently writing and would like to disable this feature if possible. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: This is not really a latex related question, and thus you're probably better of asking the overleaf support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Overleaf as well, and I don't seem to encounter that issue in the same way. For me, it's just that generally my lines are highlighted in gradient until I click away.

There is no way to remove it, because it is how Overleaf tracks change history of the document, since the latest click away, or auto-save. Unfortunately, you're just going to have to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

In overleaf, if you make changes while the track changes feature is turned on (located under the review tab) then it'll highlight the changes permanently. If you turn the feature off it will no longer highlight new changes; however, sadly there's no way to remove text highlights that appeared while the feature was turned on.

edit: It's worth noting that track changes is a premium feature on overleaf